# QString::fromUtf8 not working problem with non english characters

Tags: qt5, qstring, non-english

I am facing a problem with the `QString::fromUtf8` function.

When I use the following:

```cpp
QString::fromUtf8("Rajesh")
```

The output is OK in `QListWidget`.

But when I use

```cpp
QString::fromUtf8("राजेश")
```

I don't get राजेश as output.

Word "राजेश" is in Hindi whereas "Rajesh" is in English.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could use this:

```cpp
QString::fromUtf8( u"राजेश" );
```

For more info, you could read [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Answer (score 0):

This means that your source (.h, .cpp) files are saved in another than UTF8 encoding. Save your source files in UTF8-no-BOM and use any language you want. Be note that with Qt 5 normally you don't need to write `fromUtf8(...)` because UTF8 will be used by default.

From the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details

> ```
> QString str = "Hello";
> ```
>
> QString converts the `const char *` data into Unicode using the
> `fromUtf8()` function.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply I am using a sqlite database where hindi characters, strings are getting inserted properly but when i read that some characters are showing in QListWidget some show as blank space

Comment: @rajeshkumar ok, but then you need to edit your question to provide your actual code.